# alarm is getting cancelled in onStop but not in onDestroy android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to cancel an alarm and `PendingIntent` in the `onDestroy()` and its not working. But if I use the same code for cancelling alarm in `onStop()` its working fine. How can I cancel the alarm in `onDestroy()`. Here is my Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BroadcastObserver.getInstance().addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Intent intent = (Intent) arg;
        Log.e("MainActivity","Update method "+intent.getAction());
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setAlarm();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!checkAlarm()) {
            setAlarm();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        BroadcastObserver.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void setAlarm() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void setEndAlarm() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(EndReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    private boolean checkAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        boolean isSet = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
        Log.e("MainActivity", isSet + " :Alarm is set");
        return isSet;
    }

    private boolean checkEndAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(EndReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        boolean isSet = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
        Log.e("MainActivity", isSet + " :Alarm is set");
        return isSet;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cancelAlarm();
    }

    private void cancelAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1001, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to cancel the alarm in `onDestroy`? If it's working with `onStop` and you're setting the alarm in `onStart`, that seems like the best place for the cancelation already.

Comment: I want to implement this in a BaseActivity which has been extended by multiple activities will extend. So I want to perform cancelling in `onDestroy()` and creation in `onCreate()`. Because `onStart()` and `onStop()` will be called multiple times for all the activities going back and forth.

Comment: onDestroy is "Killable" so it may not run before killed, if any thing you must run , need working on onStop. You can implement a counter for your purpose. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: you want to cancel the alarm at onDestroy. your scenario for killing app by swipe to close app is not calling onDestroy()

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you're actually trying to achieve with this. Seems odd to be setting an alarm from _every_ activity. Perhaps there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: You do understand that `onDestroy()` of one `Activity` can be called **after** `onCreate()` of another `Activity`? In this case you may be cancelling something that was set by another `Activity`. Also, how do you know that `onDestroy()` is being called?